# Ajax Form Submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know this has been asked a million times here and I've looked at several examples, but I can't figure out why this form is submitting. The Ajax appears to not being called so I assume it's something simple like a div id issue. I've been frustrating over this 30 minutes now.

JS:

```
$('#genform').submit(function (e) {
    alert('hi');
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "month.php",
        type: "post",
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#info").html(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<!-- trigger button -->
<div class="col-md-4">
<a href="#" id="toggle" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-sm"> Bulk PDF Export <span class="caret"></span></a> 
</div>
<!--- popup form div -->
<div id="gendiv" style="display:none;">
    <form id="genform">
        <div class="form-input">
            <select name="month">
                <option value="2013-09-01">September 2013</option>
                <option value="2013-08-01">August 2013</option>
                <option value="2013-07-01">July 2013</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-input"><i class="icon-ellipsis-horizontal"></i> PGY-1  <span class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox" id="pgy1" checked name="pgy[1]"></span> 
        </div>
        <div class="form-input"><i class="icon-ellipsis-horizontal"></i> PGY-2  <span class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox" id="pgy2" checked name="pgy[2]"></span> 
        </div>
        <div class="form-input"><i class="icon-ellipsis-horizontal"></i> PGY-3  <span class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox" id="pgy3" checked name="pgy[3]"></span> 
        </div>
        <div class="form-input" style="text-align:center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Generate</button>
        </div>
        <div id="info"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KQ2nM/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because the popover clones the form and then places the html inside a div with the class `.popover-content`.

This means that the event you bound is only attached to the **original** `#genform` which is inside the hidden `#gendiv`.

Use this instead:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#genform', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "month.php",
        type: "post",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#info").html(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

This uses jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function and attaches an event handler to the `document` which basically watches for a `submit` event triggered on a form with the id `#genform`. By attaching the event handler to the `document` instead of directly to the target element it gets triggered by a `submit` event regardless of whether a form with the id `#genform` exists when the event is bound.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/KQ2nM/4/

Answer (score -1):

You are missing some closing tags:

```
<div class="form-input">
    <i class="icon-ellipsis-horizontal"></i> PGY-1 <span class="pull-right">
        <input type="checkbox" id="pgy1" checked name="pgy[1]">   </input>    <--- here
    </span>
</div>
```

And the form method (otherwise it spits up an error):

```
<form id="genform" method="POST">
```

Now django complains about the CSRF token, but that's your stuff ;)
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/KQ2nM/3/)'s the new Fiddle.

**EDIT:** It seems like I got it wrong since now it submits without calling your custom handler and Joe fixed it. But you still need to close those inputs :)